# Fill color on a number of selected shapes by user choice

Tags: vba, powerpoint

After selecting a number of shapes, this code prompts for fill color for each selected shape.

```vb
Sub ChangeColorBasedonInput()
Dim myColor(1 To 10) As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim colorChoice As Integer

myColor(1) = RGB(77, 60, 47)
myColor(2) = RGB(207, 189, 155)
myColor(3) = RGB(192, 113, 86)
myColor(4) = RGB(232, 199, 103)
myColor(5) = RGB(174, 176, 179)
myColor(6) = RGB(164, 55, 37)
myColor(7) = RGB(237, 215, 157)
myColor(8) = RGB(123, 125, 128)
myColor(9) = RGB(230, 182, 164)
myColor(10) = RGB(70, 71, 73)

On Error Resume Next

z = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count

For x = 1 To z
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(x)
        colorChoice = InputBox("Please select the color you want for Shape " & x & ", from 1 - 10")
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = myColor(colorChoice)
    End With
Next x

End Sub
```

It is a hassle to enter the color choice one by one, so I tried to write code to enter fill color selection once (from the above array and it will fill the shapes.
E.g. when I select 7, fill the shapes from myColor(7) onwards.

```vb
Sub ChangeColorBasedon_EnterOnceOnly()
Dim myColor(1 To 10) As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim colorChoice As Integer

myColor(1) = RGB(77, 60, 47)
myColor(2) = RGB(207, 189, 155)
myColor(3) = RGB(192, 113, 86)
myColor(4) = RGB(232, 199, 103)
myColor(5) = RGB(174, 176, 179)
myColor(6) = RGB(164, 55, 37)
myColor(7) = RGB(237, 215, 157)
myColor(8) = RGB(123, 125, 128)
myColor(9) = RGB(230, 182, 164)
myColor(10) = RGB(70, 71, 73)

On Error Resume Next

z = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count

colorChoice = InputBox("Please select the color you want for Shape " & x + 1 & ", from 1 - 10")

For x = 1 To z
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(x)
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = myColor(colorChoice)
    End With
    colorChoice = colorChoice + x
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting and on which line?

Answer (score 0):

Just before `Next x` add

```
If colorChoice > UBound(myColor) Then colorChoice = LBound(myColor)
```

or you may exceed the bounds of the array if too many shapes are selected